# Qualtrics Javascript event.keycode not working for respondents

Tags: javascript, html, keystroke, qualtrics

I have a Qualtrics survey block that contains a series of five questions (within a larger survey). Each question presents a sequence of words and pictures, and writes keystroke responses to the text box, using Javascript and HTML entered into the question's HTML view.

In the Javascript API window I have the below JS that manages how the questions are presented (hide proceed button) and moved on (press 'q'/keyCode 81).

Respondents are reporting that when they press 'q' nothing happens. I have tried to replicate this error in Firefox 45.0.1, Chrome 49.0.2623.110 and IE11 but I cannot replicate it and the survey operates as intended.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

    //hide input
    var InputId = $("QR~" + this.questionId);
    InputId.style.display="none";

    //hide next button
    this.hideNextButton();

    //set up key handling
    var QObj = this;
    document.onkeydown = function(event) { KeyHandler(event, QObj) }
    document.onkeypress = function(event) { KeyHandler(event, QObj) }
    });


    function KeyHandler(event, QObj)
    {

    //check keys
    if(event.keyCode == 81)
    {
        QObj.setChoiceValue(1,true);
        QObj.clickNextButton();
    }

}
```

One respondent out of about 8 has successfully completed the survey so it doesn't appear to be a universal issue.

Could it be a browser version or JFE issue?

I can post the full HTML/JS from the question if helpful.

Comment: Also, one respondent has reported seeing a 'timer' during these questions, which is very confusing as there is not timing element in these questions. Although reaction times are recorded for the keystroke responses.

Comment: It's possible the respondent is using an older browser. can you post the UserAgent of the respondents reporting the issue?

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I tested the survey on some old PCs we have, running IE8 and was able to reproduce the problem. Could it be related to this issue, that IE8 cannot accept keyCode handling events? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399150/onkeydown-and-onkeyup-events-dont-work-on-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: The userAgent for the PC that produced the error was (The PC was running IE8, not Mozilla/Firrefix as stated but I believe this is an artifact of userAgent string 'spoofing from Netscape competition days): Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)

Client Information:

JavaScript Enabled: No
Cookies Enabled: No
Device Pixel Ratio: N/ADevicePixelRatio.com
Screen Resolution: N/AWhatsMyScreenResolution.com
Browser Window: N/A
Local Time: N/A
Time Zone: N/A

Comment: Seems likely that it is an IE8 issue, I'll follow up shortly if I can find a decent way of handling this in Qualtrics. going to test a few things now.

Comment: It appears that the new jfe engine doesn't support ie8, which is reasonable as MS has cut support for the browser. I verified this during my own testing. Though some features wont run in the jfe and are still reverting to the old platform.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyRivas much appreciated. I have found a few workarounds on here so I'll give those a go. Thank again.